# How to throttle/limit the cache-store read threads?

Tags: ignite

I have implemented a cache store for my ignite caching, whenever there is a read-through operation through the cache-store, I want to limit this to single thread or  at max 2. The reason behind the same is due to the fact that the underlying cache store is a remote Rest based webservice that can only support limited number of connections. Hence I want to have limited number of requests being sent for read-through.
Please note that if I configure publicThreadPoolSize =1 , this would mean all cache.get and cache.getAll operations would be single threaded. Hence this behaviour is not desired, I want to have throttling at the cache store level only.

Thanks in advance for your response,
Mridul

Comment: I assume you have your own implementation of `CacheStore`, so you can add logic to support your requirements there. But what should happen if there are more than two threads trying to read from store through the cache?

Comment: The remote service may go down  if we have more than specific number of queries requesting data from the store.Hope this helps.

Comment: I would just have a connection pool within the cache store which would limit number of parallel connections. If there are none available, you can either wait or throw an exception. In the latter case `get()` operation will fail altogether.